# How do you carry around your lenses?

Tags: camera-bag

How do you carry them around? I own a tamrac backpack which is now unable to cope with my lenses and filters.

Comment: The title needs to be changed, it sounds like the real question has to do with carrying lenses.  It needs to be more specific, e.g. add more information about where you photograph and what is making it hard to cope. E.g. backpacking into the wild for landscape or shooting an event indoors would have different lens needs and options for coping.

Comment: @jkflein, I agree.

Comment: I think that this question should be marked as community wiki.

Comment: @Paulo Guedes: Definitely. This question can never have a single correct answer.

Comment: I'll fifth that.

Comment: I disagree; the question is too vague as it stands, and if it were edited to be more specific, then it would attract appropriately specific answers. I think the CW in this case was a mistake.

Comment: Reid has a point here.  There could be one general CW question of how do you carry lenses, but there's plenty of room for scenario-specific questions that could be really helpful, without straying into the other direction of being overly-specific.

Answer (score 1):

I currently have three lenses for my Canon EOS.  Most of the time I use a soft-sided bag with two of the lenses in the bag vertically, and one on the camera body.  I do have an aluminum briefcase style case that I use when I travel, or think that they may get banged around a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I have eight lenses plus a couple of teleconverters. I don't carry them all around all the time, one is a 120-400mm monster, but I do have a few camera bags that I use depending on the need.

Day to day, I use the Lowepro Slingshot (I can't remember the model, it was the largest one) and it usually has 5 lenses in it, one on the camera and four in various compartments along with a speedlight and a ring flash, cards, etc. It's a little hefty so I also have a small case that I use for actually walking around and it can only hold a couple of lenses (camera around the neck here).

For travel, I have a much larger case that can hold a notebook computer, the Think Tank Airport Antidote, but still fit the luggage carry on limits. It can take a bit more gear, but is even heavier as a result.

I don't actually a bag that can take all of my lenses if I want to put a camera in with it, so I tend to plan based on what I expect to need for the locations I'll be shooting. However, a few of my lenses are not really daily use types, so I don't normally need to carry them.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Lowepro Fastpack](http://products.lowepro.com/product/Fastpack-250,2086.htm) which has a nice feature of having side access to the camera compartment, meaning you don't have to throw it on the ground to get the camera out. I use it as for my everyday walkaround stuff (camera + one lens, laptop, other personal items) and when the need arises, I can fit in a DSLR body with telephoto lens, two other lenses, two flashes, and still have room for the laptop and empty generic compartment.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on my needs: I've got four different camera bags (two Tamrac slings, two ThinkTank backbacks) and use the one depending on my equipment needs.

But I never carry around *all* of my equipment. I pack only what I really need for a shoot. Most times a simple small sling bag with one body with one attached lens is enough for me.
Sometimes I add a tripod and pano head.
Sometimes I add a second lens.

If I need a lot of stuff I usually carry another spezial bag for lighting equipment.

Answer (score 1):

I have a basic large Eastpak bag for daily use. I liked it so much that I made it camera/lens-compatible: took a piece of that white packing material found in boxes for pc's etc, and cut out the exact shape of my camera and most used lenses/filters. Because I made it to fit perfectly, I like it better than any camera-specific bag I ever tried. Definitely worth a shot if you're a bit handy and if you know what equipment you'll carry most.