# Is it best to transport a camera with lens attached, or off?

Tags: lens, camera-bag, travel, equipment-protection

I'm traveling now(I'm at Aruba) and I bought me a Canon 60D with the lens kit(EFS 18-55mm). I never used a camera that has removable lens like this one, my last one was a Panasonic Lumix DMC-FZ18, so I'm going to a lot of places to take some photos, but which is the best way to carry the camera and the lens on the case? My ideas:

- Remove the lens and let the camera without any lens attached(just with the protector cover)
- Let the lens on the camera as it is

Which one is correct? If I have more stuff like: More lens, flash and other things for taking photos, how should I carry them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this picture:

[image: I am]

This is how I carry my camera (Nikon D80), 2-3 lenses and a flash. Also a small tripod (not on this picture). Everything is easy and fast to access, and stay in safe while transportation in a backpack (I travel a lot on a bicycle - you probably know how these all shakes there).

Bag for the camera is a Lowepro (don't remember a model, can look if necessary), and an Adorama Slinger lens cases (attaches to a camera bag on both sides).

Everything is still working well (knock-knock on wood).

Answer (score 10):

Keeping the lens on is usually fine, unless your luggage will be subjected to unusually rough treatment, in which case separating the camera body / lens and carefully padding each would be preferable.

For transporting multiple lenses, flash etc. a purpose built camera bag is the clear choice. These come in backpack and case forms. See also:

- [Is there a camera bag with extra space that I use as an airplane carry-on?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/camera-bag-with-extra-space-as-airplane-carry-on)
- [Which camera bag for a single DSLR camera plus 2 lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/191/which-camera-bag-for-a-single-dslr-camera-plus-2-lenses)
- [Looking for a discreet camera bag](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3143/looking-for-a-discreet-camera-bag)
- [How do you carry around your lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3484/how-do-you-carry-around-your-lenses)

Answer (score 3):

Leave the lens on if you can, but don't sweat it if you have to take the lens off. The more you take off the lens, the more of a chance that dust will get into the sensor. But I know that I've sometimes had bags that I had to take the lenses off in order to fit.

Answer (score 1):

For a camera and just one other lens, I like to use a long camera bag meant for a telephoto (I use the the Lowepro Slingshot 75AW, but any long bag will do) - with normal size lenses you can usually keep the camera attached to a lens, with another lens under it - all of the long bags I think come with an internal padded divider that keeps the lenses from hitting each other.

A flash you could clip on the outside of a case like that, generally they have some way to attach other small bags.

There are also various belt systems made, with individual lens cases... a single bag looks more non-descript though and doesn't scream "expensive camera gear".

Whatever you do, it's better to leave the camera body attached to a lens if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Nikon D800e and i travel a lot, recently i have noticed AF issues and the camera just not taking sharp images...i took it to the Nikon centre in Hong Kong and they inspected it and it seems the lens attachment plate on the lens (24-70) and the camera front have been bent...i can only attribute this to the camera being in the bag (Lowepro slingback) and constant small amounts of pressure being applied to the lens and camera...it have had it fixed thank goodness and it cost a lot but cheaper than a replacement and i now never travel with the lens attached....hope this helps

Comment: Metal parts are only permanently deformed when they experience a force that exceeds their [elastic limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yield_(engineering)). The flange on a DSLR is very strong and will certainly withstand "small amounts of pressure" no matter how long or how often they're applied. The force required to bend that flange would have to be large, like the force of an impact; whether you knew about it or not, your camera was likely dropped at some point. Removing the lens during transit may eliminate some risk, but it also creates the potential for other damage, like dust entry.